# Can't scroll through javascript map after loading page in webview

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ipad, dictionary, webview

I'm rather new to xcode. I'm developing an application which displays information of places for my project.

This are the codes in my .m file. I'm loaded the html page but I can't scroll through the map when running the application. Instead when I tap and drag, the whole webview moves.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *url = @"http://pastehtml.com/view/bjxy5ka1a.html";
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] ];
    [webView loadRequest:request];

}
```

Is it the map service is not for touchscreens or am I missing out something?
I'm using http://gothere.sg service. It has an iPhone application in the appstore.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. When I put that URL into my iPad, the map doesn't scroll. When I put it in the simulator it doesn't scroll. When I put into a browser on my laptop, it scrolls.

The gothere site seems to have a mobile interface and a standard interface. That may be the problem, but I can't get the standard interface to work on my iPad. It also appears to be still in development, as it has at least a few bugs. I cannot get the standard interface to work on my iPad, even though it's offered as an option.